# multiply RealMatrix with Complex matrix

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-commons

I am pretty new to Java and I am facing an issue I believe it can be mastered pretty easily.

I am generating a project with is linked to the `Apache - Commons Math` library.

Within the project, I'm making use quite a lot of `RealMatrix` objects. I have a method working as follows

```
public static RealMatrix DistCalc(RealMatrix YCoord, RealMatrix ZCoord){
        RealMatrix Distance = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(YCoord.getRowDimension(),ZCoord.getRowDimension());
        for(int ii = 0; ii < YCoord.getRowDimension(); ii++){
            for(int jj = 0; jj < ZCoord.getRowDimension(); jj++){
                Distance.setEntry(ii,jj,Math.sqrt((YCoord.getEntry(ii, 0) - YCoord.getEntry(jj, 0))*(YCoord.getEntry(ii, 0) - YCoord.getEntry(jj, 0)) + (ZCoord.getEntry(jj, 0) - ZCoord.getEntry(ii, 0))*(ZCoord.getEntry(jj, 0) - ZCoord.getEntry(ii, 0))));
            }
        }        
        return Distance;
    }
```

and another one generating a certain `Complex` matrix,

```
// Define the random phase for the u- component
    public static Complex[][] RandPhi(int N, int nFFT){
        Complex[][] nn_u = new Complex[N][nFFT];        
        for(int ii = 0; ii < N; ii++){
            for(int jj = 0; jj < nFFT; jj++){
                nn_u[ii][jj] = new Complex(Math.cos(new Random().nextDouble()*2*Math.PI),Math.sin(new Random().nextDouble()*2*Math.PI));
            }
        }
        return nn_u;
    }
```

Now, I'd like multiplying column-wise the `RealMatrix` **Distance** with the `Complex` matrix **nn_u**: in the end I should come up with a `Complex[N][nFFT]` matrix.

Would you mind to shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you create your own `ComplexMatrix` interface based on the `RealMatrix` interface, and that you then create your own `Array2DRowComplexMatrix` class based on the `Array2DRowRealMatrix` class. To create the class, simply [download the source code](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi), change the class name, change `double data[][]` to `Complex data[][]`, and then update all references to `data`.

Either create a `ComplexMatrix` constructor that accepts a `RealMatrix`, or else include a `multiply` method with a `RealMatrix` parameter.

Commons should have all of the methods you need, you might just need to tweak their parameter/return types a bit.

Comment: would it be any easier if I switch back to Java primitive `double[][]` type instead of `RealMatrix`? I'm currently using `RealMatrix` cause the code results cleaner and I don't have to re-invent the wheel. Btw, I'll give a try to what you are suggesting.

Comment: It's your call, all you really need is a multiply method that accepts a `Complex[][]` and a `double[][]`, and this can either be an instance method of a `ComplexMatrix` class or it could be a static method with `(Complex[][], double[][])` parameters.  Either way, download the Math source code and base your `multiply` method on the one in the `Array2DRowComplexMatrix` class - that method is the part that you don't want to have to re-implement on your own.